# Is there a way I can update the values inside a loop?

Tags: python

```py
def get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    guessed_word = ''
    for letter in secret_word:
        if letter not in letters_guessed:
            guessed_word += '_ '
        else:
            guessed_word += letter
    return guessed_word
def hangman(secret_word):
    print('Welcome to the game Hangman!')
    print('\nI am thinking of a word that is {} letters long\n'.format(str(len(secret_word))))
    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
        print('_ ',end=' ')
    guess = 6
    word = ''
    guessed_word = ''
    user_input = []
    while guess > 0:
        user_input = input('\n\nPlease guess a letter: ')
        guessed_word = get_guessed_word(secret_word,user_input)
        print(guessed_word)
        guess -= 1
        print('\nyou have {} guesses left.'.format(guess))
    return ''
print(hangman('apple'))
```

I want to return all the values updated but I get the values for each loop
Example: output should be if the secre word is 'apple'

please guess a letter:a
a _ _ _ _
Please guess a letter:p
a p p _ _

but my output is:

Please guess a letter: a
a _ _ _ _
Please guess a letter :P
_ p p _ _

Comment: Please relate your question to your code: what do you want to update, how, and inside which loop?

Comment: I have added the sample output can you please check now @DYZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
user_input = input('\n\nPlease guess a letter: ')
```

to:

```
user_input += input('\n\nPlease guess a letter: ')
```

so that you're appending to it rather than replacing it.